# AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, x509certificate, client-certificates, self-signed-certificate

I have 2 **asp.net core 3.1** applications. one of them is an **IdentityServer** and the other one is a **Client** which make **OpenID Connect to IdentityServer if** action method have Authorize Attribute.

1. My IdentityServer has nothing strange. There are just some **InMemory Clients and Users**:

```
// User 1
{
   "SubjectId": 1,
   "Username": "MyName",
   "Password": "MyPassword"
}

// Client 1
{
   "ClientId": "ClientID",
   "ClientName": "This is MVC1 Client",
   "ClientSecrets": [{
       "Value": "ClientSecret"
    }],
   "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "authorization_code" ],
   "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:7573/signin-oidc" ],
   "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:7573/signin-oidc" ],
   "AllowedScopes": [
       "openid",
       "profile",
       "address",
       "email",
       "phone"
    ],
    "RequirePkce": true,
    "AllowPlainTextPkce": false
}
```

2. And this is my Client application:

```
services
        .AddAuthentication(options => {
              options.DefaultScheme = "Cookie";
              options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OIDC";})

        .AddCookie("Cookie")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("OIDC", options => { // This config used for Authentication
              options.SignInScheme = "Cookie";
              options.SignOutScheme = "Cookie";

              options.Authority = "http://192.168.34.33:80"; // My remote Server
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

              options.ClientId = "MVC1";
              options.ClientSecret = "MVC1";

              options.ResponseType = "code";
              options.UsePkce = true;

              options.SaveTokens = true;

              options.ResponseMode = "query";

              options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";

              options.Scope.Clear();
              options.Scope.Add("openid");
              options.Scope.Add("profile");
              options.Scope.Add("email");
              options.Scope.Add("address");
              options.Scope.Add("phone");
      });
```

`And This Configuration WORK Well with HTTP` **But NOT HTTPS**


[image]

`when i press login, it work ok and after authentication, redirect me back to the client`


The problem is when i change **Authority URL** to **HTTPS**, I receive a **remote certificate** error and its right, because there is no valid certificate in my IIS 
So:

1. I create a **self signed certificate** in my IIS and Bind it to my Project:

[image]

2. And also i add this certificate to my **trusted root certification authorities** of client machine:


   [image]
3. I change `options.Authority` and `options.RequireHttpsMetadata` to this:

```
    options.Authority = "https://192.168.34.33:4430"; // My remote Server
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
```

Now when i click on Privacy button in my client application (Authorize action method), i see certificate error:

[image]

Please Help Me. I Really Really Need Help. Thank You :))

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the IP-address and HTTPS together, like here:

```
   options.Authority = "https://192.168.34.33:4430"; // My remote Server
   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
```

To get TLS/HTTPS to work, you must have the domain name of the server. Otherwise, who can the client know who it is talking to?